# Extract email from string instead of whole line from string

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to grab just the email address from a string of text using Regex.

**How can I get my simple code to extract just the email address and not the whole line?**

```
demo_text = """hsds hjdsjd ksdkj

Reason: 550 abc@gmail.com... No such user

sdhjsdjh
"""
# the following code extracts the whole line "Reason: 550 abc@gmail.com... No such user"
# how do I just extract "abc@gmail.com"?
email = re.search("Reason: 550 (.+)... No such user", demo_text).group(0)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.group(0)` returns the whole string. You want `.group(1)`:

```
email = re.search("Reason: 550 (.*?)... No such user", demo_text).group(1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Retrieve group 1 instead.

```
....group(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

A more general regex solution would be:

```
r"[\w.]+@[\w.]+"
```

Comment: I'd try this one as well: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html. That one is for validation only, so I'd use it for emails extracted using this regex.

Comment: @Blender: I like that one. It's short, readable, and concise :)

Comment: @Joel: Please stop spreading **BROKEN** regular expressions for email addresses.

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
email_id = re.search(r'([\w.])+@([\w.])+', demo_text)
email_id.group(1) # the username part
email_id.group(2) # the host part
```

Comment: That regex doesn't look right. I think you meant to use backslashes instead of forward slashes

Comment: @Joel yep i meant to use '\' (ans-replace '/' with '\' )

Comment: @Vivek: please not that your regexp will fail on the simplest of cases (you omit many valid characters); you've got the `+` in the wrong place in *both* cases (the first should be within the capture group, and the second is next to the `@`; and even if you had placed them correctly, your regexp would capture the trailing `.`s.

Comment: @Len thank you for guiding me correctly... i edited the answer now its correct... so just thanks man

Comment: @Vivek your RegExp not work. I test with `test@example.com` and return only first and last caracters in groups.